# How can I mimic an android process becoming a background process?

Tags: android, background-process

I have crashes occurring in my app when the drops in the LRU-application list within androids OS (See http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle). This is due savedInstanceStates not being handled properly. It's really painful and time consuming to constantly have to open my app and then open like ten other applications just to mimic these errors and verify my fixes.

Is there a quick way to mimic this via code?

Answer (score 0):

The way I test those cases is go to **Settings > Developer Options**. Scroll to the very bottom and enable **Don't keep activities**. Also, set the **Background process limit** to **No background processes**.

Open your app and hit the home button once you are in the activity you want to test and then bring it back from the Recent Apps list.

Hope this helps.